# Equation of a plane Parallel to 2 vectors and passing through Tip of another

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I'm struggling to answer this question: determine the equation of the plane parallel to *v* and *w* passing through the tip of *u*. i have the coordinates for all of them as (*x, y, z*) but as its an assignment i can only ask the general format, not with the actual numbers. i know the cross product can be used for perpendicular but no clue what to do here?? Found a similar question online but not sure i understand the answer...

Any help would be extremely appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say $\vec h=\vec w \times \vec v$ is the vector orthogonal to $\vec w $ and $\vec v$, so the equation of the plane orthogonal to $\vec h$ and passing through the tip of $\vec u$ is:
$$
\vec h \cdot (\vec x-\vec u)=0
$$

Comment: thank you so muxh! sorry this  might be stupid, so its the cross product vector h, then dot product with (x - u) = 0- but whats the x vector??? sorry!!!!

Comment: The tip of $\vec x$ is a point of the plane.